# How to resolve invalid lockfile size of "gnupg_spawn_agent_sentinel.lock"?

Tags: git, gnupg, sign, gpg-agent

The issue begins with me unable to sign my Git commit.

```bash
$ git commit --verbose -S -sam "Attempt to sign commit"

gpg: invalid size of lockfile 'C:\Users\username\.gnupg/gnupg_spawn_agent_sentinel.lock'
gpg: cannot read lockfile
gpg: can't connect to the agent: Invalid argument
gpg: keydb_search failed: No agent running
gpg: skipped "KEY_ID_ABC123": No agent running
gpg: signing failed: No agent running
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

It seems that I'm unable to sign because the GPG agent is not running, and the agent is not running because of the invalid lockfile size of `gnupg_spawn_agent_sentinel.lock`.

Running `gpg -K` also gives me a similar error:

```bash
$ gpg -K

gpg: invalid size of lockfile 'C:\Users\username\.gnupg/gnupg_spawn_agent_sentinel.lock'
gpg: cannot read lockfile
gpg: can't connect to the agent: Invalid argument
```

I checked the file size of `~/.gnupg/gnupg_spawn_agent_sentinel.lock`

```bash
$ ll ~/.gnupg/ | grep gnupg_spawn_agent_sentinel

-rw-r--r-- 1 username 1049089     0 Dec 16 16:53 gnupg_spawn_agent_sentinel.lock
```

It shows that `gnupg_spawn_agent_sentinel.lock` is 0 bytes! Home come? And how can I proceed from here to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently deleting the corrupted `.lock` file resolves my issue.

```bash
# "delete" by backing up, just in case
mv ~/.gnupg/gnupg_spawn_agent_sentinel.lock ~/.gnupg/gnupg_spawn_agent_sentinel.lock.bak-YYYY-MM-DD
```

I'd appreciate if anyone can elaborate what the lock file is for, as well as side-effects of this solution, if any.